# Skip first 5 lines of CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm sure this is trivial but after an age pulling my hair out it's time for you friendly SO folks to save me.

I want to operate on a CSV file that I'm reading with the CSV class as follows:

```
CSV.foreach(@path_to_file) do |row|
    #doing stuff here
end
```

However the file has 5 lines above the header that needs to be removed (the `foreach` method barfs when it encounters these lines).

I'm guessing I can read the file and reassemble without the first 5 lines but I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this.

The reason the CSV methods don't work is that in the top 5 lines are characters that the CSV class doesn't like; it returns `CSV:MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 3`.

So I don't think I can use the CSV class unless I can get it to remove the lines before it tries to parse the CSV.

Comment: There's other methods besides `foreach`, like `open` itself which gives you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Please see my edit above with more detail re: the issue

Comment: If you want to process a non-CSV file, you'll need to read it in manually, strip off the first five lines, reassemble it, then dump it back into the CSV parser. What you seemed to be describing at first was omitting the first five lines of otherwise CSV data.

Comment: If it's a CSV file, perhaps you aren't reading it as the correct character encoding. We can't tell because you don't provide the lines in question, but that does happen easily.

Comment: Nope, it's just a bunch of comments at the top of the file, and given CSV doesn't have a standard way of commenting lines it is just a bit of a pain having to pre-process it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to bypass the CSV module by constructing a valid CSV string from your otherwise incompatible data:

```
CSV.parse(File.readlines(path).drop(5).join) do |row|
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
csv = CSV.open @path_to_file
csv.drop(5).each do |row|
  #doing stuff here
end
```

Comment: Throws a CSV:MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 3. (which is why I need to remove these lines before parsing the CSV)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to simulate your error with a minimal working example:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.parse(DATA.read,:col_sep=>';',:headers=>true,
  ) do |row|
  p row
end

__END__
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;4
here we have an error because there is a " in the text;
1;2;3;4
"1";"2";3;4
```

This return the same error you have:  `Illegal quoting in line 3. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)`

When you know , which string causes the problem, you can skip the line with the option `:skip_lines`:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.parse(DATA.read,:col_sep=>';',:headers=>true,
    :skip_lines=> /a " in the text/
  ) do |row|
  p row
end

__END__
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;4
here we have an error because there is a " in the text;
1;2;3;4
"1";"2";3;4
```

The result:

```
#<CSV::Row "a":"1" "b":"2" "c":"3" "d":"4">
#<CSV::Row "a":"1" "b":"2" "c":"3" "d":"4">
#<CSV::Row "a":"1" "b":"2" "c":"3" "d":"4">
```

---

If your CSV has no quoted content (inside `"`), then you may also try to use an unused character as a qoute char:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.parse(DATA.read,:col_sep=>';',:headers=>true,
    quote_char: '§'
  ) do |row|
  p row
end

__END__
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;4
here we have an error because there is a " in the text;
1;2;3;4
"1";"2";3;4
```

The result of my example shows also, what happens if you use quoted content (see the last line):

```
#<CSV::Row "a":"1" "b":"2" "c":"3" "d":"4">
#<CSV::Row "a":"here we have an error because there is a \" in the text" "b":nil "c":nil "d":nil>
#<CSV::Row "a":"1" "b":"2" "c":"3" "d":"4">
#<CSV::Row "a":"\"1\"" "b":"\"2\"" "c":"3" "d":"4">
```