# Ruby CSV headers not in the first line

Tags: ruby, csv

I would like to read CSV file with (headers: true option), but the first 5 lines of my file contain unwanted data. So I want line 6 to be a header and start reading file with line 6.

But when I read a file `CSV.readlines("my_file.csv", headers: true).drop(5)`, 
it still uses line 1 as a header. How can I set line 6 as a header?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip the first line of a CSV file and make the second line the header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896899/how-to-skip-the-first-line-of-a-csv-file-and-make-the-second-line-the-header)  Just extend the loop to read the first x -lines.

Comment: If your first 5 lines have a flag you may use the skip_lines-option. See an example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36099760/676874

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pre-read the garbage lines before you start CSV.

```
require 'csv'

File.open("my_file.csv") do |f|
  5.times { f.gets }
  csv = CSV.new(f, headers: true)
  puts csv.shift.inspect
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution

```
require 'csv'

my_header = CSV.readlines("my_file.csv").drop(5).first

CSV.readlines("my_file.csv", headers: my_header).drop(6) do |row|

 do something .....
end
```