# Skip rows before the header in CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I tried searching but couldn't find a question regarding my problem. Let's say I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
Metadata line 1
Metadata line 2
Metadata line 3
Metadata line 4
foo,bar,baz
apple,orange,banana
cashew,almond,walnut
```

The line `foo,bar,baz` is the header, and the following lines are the corresponding data. When I write my ruby code like so:

```
CSV.foreach("filename.csv",:headers=>true) do |row|
  puts "#{row}"
end
```

It clearly breaks. What's the best way to skip the lines before the header? Currently I'm thinking I could do something like:

```
Find the first row with commas and get line number
Extract that line as an array
Pass that array to :headers
```

But this feels cumbersome - if I know exactly what line the header is, what's the best way to jump to that line and ignore everything previously? Is this possible? If this is a question that has been asked before, I will happily devour those answers, perhaps my search-fu just isn't good enough.

Thank you so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip the first line of a CSV file and make the second line the header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896899/how-to-skip-the-first-line-of-a-csv-file-and-make-the-second-line-the-header) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889886/ruby-csv-headers-not-in-the-first-line?lq=1  Just extend the loop to read the first x -lines

Answer (score 3):

There is a `skip_lines` option to CSV.  Not exactly clear if it will skip header lines or just rows, but worth a shot.

> :skip_lines - When set to an object responding to match, every line
>   matching it is considered a comment and ignored during parsing. When
>   set to a String, it is first converted to a Regexp. When set to nil no
>   line is considered a comment. If the passed object does not respond to
>   match, ArgumentError is thrown.

Comment: An example can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36099760/676874

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many metadata lines there are, you can just eat them before creating the CSV object.

Can could of course also do something useful with them, but that's up to you!

```
require 'csv'

3.times { DATA.readline }

csv = CSV.new(DATA, headers: true, return_headers: false)
csv.read.each do |row|
  p row
end
# => #<CSV::Row "header1":"1" "header2":"2">
# => #<CSV::Row "header1":"3" "header2":"4">
# => #<CSV::Row "header1":"5" "header2":"6">
p csv.headers
# => ["header1", " header2"]

__END__
# I know
# there are 3 lines
# here, so I can skip them.
header1,header2
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
require 'csv'

while (header = DATA.readline) !~ /,.*,/
end
csv = CSV.new(DATA.read, headers: header)
csv.each do |row|
  p row
end
p csv.headers

__END__
Metadata line 1
Metadata line 2
Metadata line 3
Metadata line 4
foo,bar,baz
apple,orange,banana
cashew,almond,walnut
```

One warning: [Nicks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954414/676874) 3rd data line (`# here, so I can skip them.`) contains only one comma. So your rule *Find the first row with commas* could lead to a misunderstanding. You can use the regex `/,.*,/` but then you must have at least two commas in the header to be detected as the header.

In other words: It is essential to have maximum one comma before the header line and to have more then one comma in the real header line.

Remark 2: `DATA` is a special ruby construct that can be replaced with a file handle (e.g. the f in `File.open(filename){|f| ...}`.